# CSS background image not showing up?

Tags: html, css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blahblah.css">
    </head>

    <body>


    </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
height: 1370px;
background-image: url("C:/Users/blah/Desktop/Website/images/blah.jpg");
}
```

Not sure why this is. Any help? The image is coming up fine as an  but for some reason as a background image it is not coming up. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Also have tried url(filename.jpg) to no avail

Comment: What happens if you try to load C:/Users/blah/Desktop/Website/images/blah.jpg directly into the browser? Does it show up?

Answer (score 3):

You can't load an image off your file system this way.  Assuming your website lives in "C:/Users/blah/Desktop/Website/", try

```
body {
    height: 1370px;
    background-image: url('images/blah.jpg');
}
```

You need a relative path from the location of the CSS file

Comment: Thanks for your response. It doesnt seem to be coming up even while the image is in the same folder as the HTML/CSS when its listed just as 'blah.jpg'

Comment: Is your CSS definitely being loaded?  can you set any other properties?  Try 'background-color: #f00;' and see if it turns red.

Comment: See Mr Lister's comment on your answer below...  bad markup on your meta tag is ignoring your stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Is your Windows username actually "blah"? If so, awesome, but if not, and it has spaces in it, it can sometimes create a problem fetching files. Why not try to fetch it with the URL: 
images/blah.jpg

Comment: Probably obfuscation. He doesn't want us to guess that his Windows username is actually Zack.